# Scala's parser combinator compare before parse

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm looking for a way with Scala's parser combinator to match with regex pefore parse it.

Example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object MetaCommandParser extends RegexParsers with App {

  def parseSub: Parser[Object] = (parseElement <~ "=>") ~ parseExpression.*

  def parseElement: Parser[Object] = """\w+""".r

  def parseOr: Parser[Object] = listElements

  def listElements: Parser[Object] = parseExpression ~ opt("|" ~ listElements)

  def parseExpression: Parser[Object] = parseElement | parseOr

  def parseMetaCommand(s: String) = {
    MetaCommandParser.parseAll(parseSub, s) match {
      case Success(result, _) => result
      case Failure(msg, _)    => throw new Exception("FAILURE: " + msg)
      case Error(msg, _)      => throw new Exception("ERROR: " + msg)
    }
  }

  println(parseMetaCommand("operation => test"));
}
```

Types:

```
sealed trait Command;
case class Sub(tag: Word, sub: List[Expression]) extends Command;
case class ReplaceBy(tag: Word, sub: List[Expression]) extends Command;

sealed trait Expression;
case class Or(elements: Set[Expression]) extends Expression;
case class Reference(tag: String) extends Expression;
case class Option(element: Expression) extends Expression;
case class Word(tag: String) extends Expression;
case object Empty extends Expression;
```

If I execute my parser on parseSub with this expression:
"operation => test"

I have a StackOverflow. My parser parse well to Sub(Word(operation), Word(test)) but the error comes right after. I think the parser tried to evaluate an empty String on parseExpression to end "parseExpression.*" but loop in listElements. If I can make sure that my entry is valid before call parseExpression, I think it can solve my problem (the parseValidString function)!

So I'm trying to verify that my entry matches this regex to avoid an infinite loop, I don't see how to do it :/

Thanks!

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you have a complete minimal working example.

Comment: Your `parseExpression` and `listElements` rules are mutually left-recursive, but that's probably not the problem in this case because it doesn't look like `listElements` would even be reached (because it would just always go into `parseElement` which comes first and also matches. I'm with Travis: you'll need to post a working example (meaning one that can be copied and pasted into a scala file, which will compile and reproduce the infinite loop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post to add the complete code! The println throw a StackOverflow exception and I would to solve it

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making some changes to your code to make it shorter and compilable. Specifically I've removed all your actions as they've used data types that weren't defined anywhere and also weren't necessary to reproduce the problem, changed the return types of everything to `Object` accordingly, removed `parseValidString` because it both wasn't used and didn't compile (wrong type) and then removed every alternative that could be removed without fixing the stack overflow. For the record, this is what people want when they ask for a minimal working code.

Comment: In general seeing which parts of the code you can and can't remove without making the error go away is also a good thing to do in general - even when you're not asking a question on the Internet - simply because it will give you a much better idea of which part of the code is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my types, indeed. I add them :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `parseExpression` and `listElements` rules are mutually left-recursive (via `parseOr`). In my comment I've suggested that this probably wouldn't cause the stack overflow here because `parseElement` is tried before `listElements`, meaning that `listElements` would never be reached (which is another problem in and of itself).

However, since you're using `parseExpression` in a `*` loop, it will be applied repeatedly until it fails, which means that all of its alternatives will be tried in the end. So `listElements` will be reached and the left recursion does indeed cause your stack overflow. You can also see this from the fact that the stack overflow disappears if you comment out the `| parseOr` in `parseExpression`.

Comment: For the ``parseExpression. *``, It's also what I deduced, hence I think adding a string validity test before calling ``parseExpression`` would allow solve the problem:
Replace ``parseExpression.*`` by ``validString.*`` where ``validString`` do (pseudo code):
``if string match """.+""".r then parseExpression``

Comment: @oromis The `*` isn't the problem, it's only the reason why the problem occurs even though it would otherwise be masked by the fact that your alternatives have the wrong order. The problem is the left recursion.

Comment: Okay, I see. There is a way to keep the same format (parseExpression followed by "|" and parseExpression) without having to prefix to differentiate?

Comment: @Oromis To parse infix operators using Scala parser combinators, you'd use precedence climbing. A production that basically boils down to `expression ::= expression "|" expression` can't work in a recursive descent parser (which Scala parser combinators are) because it's left recursive. Furthermore it's ambiguous as you don't specify precedence or associativity.

Comment: Okay, thanks you! I will therefore review my grammar